# JRuby/Gem logging "Ignoring thrift-0.9.0 because its extensions are not built"

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, jruby, thrift

Recently began getting an error whenever I run my ruby code.

```
Ignoring thrift-0.9.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine thrift --version 0.9.0
```

The thrift gem is a dependency of another gem, locked into version 0.9.0.

I've tried the suggested without any changes to behavior:

- gem pristine thrift --version 0.9.0
- [Thrift Ruby gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649984/thrift-ruby-gem) (Flag was actually already there, tried removing it too)
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/147939/ruby-on-os-x-10-9-ignoring-gems-because-extensions-are-not-built (Updated bundler, as well)
- [Thrift gem and JRuby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712531/thrift-gem-and-jruby) isn't an option for me as the gem is a dependency, not one used by my application.

Pretty stumped by this, ultimately the error doesn't seem to be causing any real problems, but the message seems to log out to StandardError triggering some alerts for the application.

EDIT: Looks like error is only thrown when code is packed up into a .jar and executed from there, executing from ruby code directly no error is thrown. Going to re-attempt to revert JRuby version to 1.7.19 from 1.7.20 and rebuild the .jar to see if the issue resolves.

UPDATE: Reverting to JRuby version 1.7.19 resolved this issue. In the short term I'll be resolving this issue with this solution. When I revisit this and try to figure out why this happened I'll update it here.

Comment: Edit, just updated the title to something a little more descriptive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverting to JRuby version 1.7.19 resolved this issue. In the short term I'll be resolving this with this solution.

When I revisit updating JRuby and try to figure out why this happened I'll update it accordingly.